# How to set cookie for redirected page using jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm trying to set cooking for the redirected page (as below) but it wasn't carried to the redirected page. Wondering if anyone can help me how I need to set the cookie for it to be available for redirected page.

```
URI location = null;
    try {
        location = new URI("../lin/oq");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Response.temporaryRedirect(location).cookie(new NewCookie("userId", userId,"/", "localhost",null,10000, false),new NewCookie("token",token.getToken(), null,null,null,10000, false),new NewCookie("org",org, null,null,null,10000, false),new NewCookie("courseId", courseId, null,null,null,10000, false)).build();
```